# Why does biber increase compilation time of pdflatex runs dramatically (factor 2.8!!)?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, pdftex, biber, performance

Since I am using biber, the compilation time for my document has increased dramatically.
It's a dissertation with <300 pages and a full `latexmk` compilation suddenly needed 26 minutes which is not acceptable IMHO.

I already read, that `biber` might be slower than `bibtex` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53302/4009), **but can it really make *such* a difference?**

I already described the problem here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230749/4009 ) and narrowed the problem down to `biber` which seems to have a large impact on compiling time.

I use the following biblatex setup:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=biber, 
 defernumbers,useprefix,firstinits=true, maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
```

### My question

- Is `biber` really that much slower than `bibtex`
- Can I do anything to still use `biber` but decrease compiling time?
- It seems that it is not the `biber` run itself, that makes compilation slow, but using `backend=biber` slows down pdflatex a lot
- can I use other options (kind of a draft mode) to speed up biber and only use the slow compilation for the final versions?

Unfortunately, I've switched all my input files (`.tex`, `.bib`) to UTF-8 encoding, as I head problems with exotic characters and it seems to me there is no easy way back to the good old  `latin1` times. And it seems, that UTF8 requires the biber backend.

### Test setup

- my LaTeX document, limited to one long chapter by `\includeonly`,
- 98 pages with many many references, many of them in large tables.
- large `.bib` file (5.6 MB) with >3000 references, 350 of them cited in the document
- I'm compiling from OS X terminal to measure the duration of the compilation:
  `latexmk -C; time pdflatex main.tex`

### Test results

#### with biber:

- biber cache removed once with `` rm -rf `biber --cache` ``
- `latexmk -C; time pdflatex Diss.tex`
  Output written on Diss.pdf (83 pages, 2130562 bytes).
  real    2m17.499s
  user    1m47.626s
  sys 0m1.030s
- `biber Diss`
  real    0m27.257s
  user    0m20.568s
  sys 0m1.247s
- `pdflatex Diss.tex`
  Output written on Diss.pdf (95 pages, 2453607 bytes).
  real    4m7.708s
  user    3m27.864s
  sys 0m1.029s
- again `pdflatex Diss.tex`
  Output written on Diss.pdf (95 pages, 2452370 bytes).
  real    4m33.769s
  user    3m36.491s
  sys 0m1.252s

#### with `bibtex8`

- remove all `aux` and `bbl` files etc.
- `latexmk -C; time pdflatex Diss.tex`
  Output written on Diss.pdf (82 pages, 2130383 bytes).
  **real  0m48.470s**
  user    0m19.161s
  sys 0m0.522s
- time `bibtex Diss`
  (There were 200 error messages) *sure :-(*
  real    0m1.258s
  user    0m0.850s
  sys 0m0.061s
- time `pdflatex Diss.tex`
  Output written on Diss.pdf (95 pages, 2452225 bytes).
  real    2m26.433s
  user    1m44.921s
  sys 0m0.932s
- second `pdflatex Diss.tex`
  Output written on Diss.pdf (95 pages, 2450936 bytes).
  real    2m27.148s
  user    1m51.958s
  sys 0m0.953s

## My `.biber.conf`

path: `~/.biber.conf`

```xml
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="Annote" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="Abstract" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="Keywords" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="comment" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
     </maps>
   </sourcemap>
</config>
```

- Is this ok?
- Are the field names case sensitive?
- is something missing here?

## Test 2 with example document

I set up an example document using the `biblatex-example.bib` file included in `TeXLive 2014`. For details please see my [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231066/4009) , as it seems to crash the question, if I insert that much text here.
The sample document compiles 80% faster with `bibtex`!
Maybe you want to try it on your machine and see how long it takes?

Comment: I see 0 minutes and 27 seconds

Comment: Mhh, obviously Biber takes longer to compile as you already hinted at. It should not make your `pdflatex` run significantly longer though (sure, if you use BibTeX you cannot use all of Biber's features and we load `biblatex1.sty` and not `biblatex2.sty`). But I doubt that we can actually compare `pdflatex`'s compile times here since due to the errors you don't get the same output (probably a lot of entries are skipped - less for `pdflatex` to write out).

Comment: @MaxNoe: as I wrote in my question, it is not the biber run itself but the pdflatex runs which take much longer with biber!

Comment: @Moewe: hm, unfortunately I have no copy of the PDF created with biber, but the bibtex version has 291 references in the bibliography, which is not that bad. Which info do you need to see if the results can be compared or not?

Comment: You might be able to speed up Biber (not sure if you are really interested in that) by not having all the references in the `.bib` file, but only the ones you actually cite. `5.6MB` is quite hefty. - Though Biber only really processes entries if they are cited, so the performance gain might be quite small.

Comment: Where does the 26 minutes come from? The times you show don't seem to support that....

Comment: @cfr: the test above is done with only 1 chapter of 98 pages. The 26 minutes were the shocking result of one latexmk run of the complete document (nearly 300 pages)

Comment: If you run the sequence pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex manually, how long does that take? Note that you do not always need a third pdflatex run with biblatex/biber.

Comment: I would just compare the bibliography output by Biber vs the one after a BibTeX run. If there is roughly the same number of entries in a very similar format, it should be fine. I would really like to see an example of this live (I realise that is probably a bit too much to ask for) since I would not have expected the Biber "goodies" to hold up compilation significantly (though there is unarguably more for LaTeX to process).

Comment: @cfr: what do you mean by "run manually"? Am I not doing that already by running the commands in terminal in my test setup?

Comment: I would not be running a complete compilation sequence every time. In general, you don't need all your references, cross-references etc. resolved each time you compile a draft. I'd just use a simple `pdflatex` run in most cases, only doing the additional stuff when required.

Comment: @Martin I meant: as opposed to using `latexmk`.

Comment: @cfr: I already do that, but >3 minutes is still a long time if I could have the same result in 40 seconds. I also use `auctex` and often compile only the current region to check if I did not add new mistakes with my edit, but that still felt painfully slow suddenly, so I tried to find the root cause.

Comment: @moewe: as you can imagine I do hesitate so give the complete "works" outside. :-( Maybe we can still find a way to find out what's making things so slow in my case, cause I think that's still not normal. How can I extract only the cited references from my .bib file?

Comment: `biber --output_format=bibtex file` should give you a `.bib` file with only the cited entries. If you have time you could try and replicate your problem with `biblatex-examples.bib` (comes with `biblatex` and is automatically found by LaTeX) and some blind text, so you don't have to upload sensitive things.

Comment: On my pc using pdflatex in "biber-mode" slows down the compilation by a factor around 2. I don't find this surprising. You only have to compare the bbl-files created by biber and bibtex: biber provides much more information and pdflatex has to handle it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ok, but how do you explain that the first run of pdflatex takes so much longer? the .bbl file is created only after the first biber run which is afterwards, afaik and during its first run, pdflatex does not have to handle the informative bbl log file. But still it's a good hint - I discovered that biber prints all the abstracts and keywords in the .bbl file!! This could be a hint, because pdflatex has to process all that each time... but it still does not explain the duration of the first pdflatex run.

Comment: @PLK: I hope it's ok, that I address you directly, as you seem to be the expert for biber. Could you have a look at my question and give me a hint how to reduce my compiling time?

Comment: I get a factor of around 20% in the first compilation when I simply cite everything from biblatex-examples.bib. The main difference between biber and bibtex here is that in "biber mode" pdflatex write a 2000-lines-`.bcf`, but only some lines in the aux and a small bib when in bibtex mode. Btw: `.bbl` is not a log-file, it is your bib prepared for pdflatex.

Comment: @Ulrike: could you share with me your example .tex document?

Comment: Have you tried removing options from biblatex to find the most time-consuming one? There is a `draft` option for biblatex to speed up compilation.

Comment: @JonasNyrup: in a first attempt I removed all options except the backend, but that did not speed up biber (see my answer below)

Comment: Have you considered asking the maintainers of Biber why this might be happening?

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I thought I had done that, but it seems I did not directly. In this answer here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53302/4009 ) the maintainer states that there are good reasons, why `biber` is slower than `bibtex` , but I'll ask him about this question here. However it would help me a lot if **other people could repeat my "benchmark" on their hardware to see how much time it takes on a recent computer.**

Comment: With `biblatex-example.bib`, a compilation with Biber is only about 60% slower than with BibTeX, not the orders of magnitude that were being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

## General Test setup for performance comparison

I've set up a test file which uses the `biblatex-examples.bib` References included in `TeXLive 2014`.
It cites each reference 10 times (not very elegant, but it works).

### Results:

#### with `biber` backend

- If I cite each source only 1 time (instead of 10), it takes **29 seconds** for the whole script to run **with biber** (3x pdflatex, 1x biber).
- If I *cite each source 10 times*, it takes already **1min36sec** for the script (with biber).

#### with `bibtex` backend

- If I change to `backend=bibtex` (still each source cited 10 times), the whole script needs **less then 18 seconds** - this is **80% less than with `biber`!!**

#### further tests:

- using 10 times `\nocite{*}` instead of citing each source separately reduces the time with biber to **21 sec**!
- removing all options from biblatex (except backend=biber) and again citing each source 10 times separately does not decrease compiling time (1min40sec)

### Compiler scripts:

#### run: `time compile-bibtex.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf `biber -cache`

time pdflatex -interaction=batchmode BiberPerformance.tex

time bibtex Biberperformance

time pdflatex -interaction=batchmode BiberPerformance.tex
time pdflatex -interaction=batchmode BiberPerformance.tex
```

#### run: `time compile-biber.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf `biber -cache`

time pdflatex -interaction=batchmode BiberPerformance.tex

time biber Biberperformance

time pdflatex -interaction=batchmode BiberPerformance.tex
time pdflatex -interaction=batchmode BiberPerformance.tex
```

### LaTeX source code `BiberPerformance.tex`

```
## \documentclass{scrbook}

%%%% {PACKAGES} %%%%
\usepackage[UKenglish, ngerman]{babel} %Sprachpakete Brit. Englisch, Deutsch Neue Rechtschreibung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1, T1]{fontenc} %Kodierungen für Text 1 und Text Symbols
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage{textcomp} %für Mü-Symbol
\usepackage{blindtext}

%Pakete für Zusatzfunktionen
\usepackage{hyperref} %Automatisches Verlinken der PDF-Datei


%Weitere Pakete
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex, defernumbers, useprefix,firstinits=true, maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}  % für bessere Literaturverzeichnisse
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}



%In Biblatex URL ignorieren, wenn DOI existiert (Quelle: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5779/4009) 
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}%
  }{%
  }%
}


\usepackage{csquotes} % Empfohlen bei Verwendung von biblatex



\begin{document}

%\nocite{*}


\chapter{Test}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}


\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}

\cite{westfahl:space}
\cite{set}
\cite{stdmodel}
\cite{aksin}
\cite{angenendt}
\cite{baez/article}
\cite{bertram}
\cite{gillies}
\cite{glashow}
\cite{herrmann}
\cite{kastenholz}
\cite{murray}
\cite{reese}
\cite{shore}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\cite{spiegelberg}
\cite{springer}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\cite{aristotle:physics}
\cite{aristotle:poetics}
\cite{aristotle:rhetoric}
\cite{augustine}
\cite{averroes/bland}
\cite{averroes/hannes}
\cite{averroes/hercz}
\cite{cicero}
\cite{coleridge}
\cite{companion}
\cite{cotton}
\cite{gerhardt}
\cite{gonzalez}
\cite{hammond}
\cite{iliad}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\cite{knuth:ct:c}
\cite{knuth:ct:d}
\cite{knuth:ct:e}
\cite{knuth:ct:related}
\cite{malinowski}
\cite{maron}
\cite{massa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa}
\cite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\cite{nussbaum}
\cite{piccato}
\cite{vangennep}
\cite{vangennep:related}
\cite{vazques-de-parga}
\cite{worman}
\cite{britannica}
\cite{gaonkar}
\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{jaffe}
\cite{westfahl:frontier}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\cite{kant:ku}
\cite{nietzsche:historie}
\cite{brandt}
\cite{hyman}
\cite{pines}
\cite{moraux}
\cite{salam}
\cite{cms}
\cite{baez/online}
\cite{ctan}
\cite{itzhaki}
\cite{markey}
\cite{wassenberg}
\cite{almendro}
\cite{kowalik}
\cite{laufenberg}
\cite{sorace}
\cite{chiu}
\cite{padhye}
\cite{geer}
\cite{loh}
\cite{jcg}
\cite{sarfraz}
\cite{moore:related}
\cite{kullback:reprint}
\cite{kullback:related}
\cite{matuz:doody}
\cite{doody}
\cite{moore}
\cite{vangennep:trans}
\cite{vizedom:related}
\cite{kullback}
\cite{wilde}


 \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: You do realise that your MWE would have been slightly shorter had you used `\nocite{*}` instead of citing each item manually?

Comment: yes, I do, but I wanted to make pdflatex print each single citation and not only [1-90]. I'm not sure, if that makes a difference in compiling time.

Comment: Aha! For exactly that purpose the new [`citeall`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeall) packages was created (it is very new, so I'm not sure if it is available right now.) Plus I'm not sure whether printing the citations vs. not printing them makes a difference (but then I've been wrong before about things like this.)

Comment: @moewe: nocite is a great performance booster for biber - I should use that in my dissertation and remove all the cite commands ;-)

Comment: It is rather inevitable - biber is not comparable to bibtex any more. Its functional set is  a large superset of bibtex.It's also not in C, which bibtex is. I may look into adding options to disable  parts of the internals whe.n drafting or when certain things are not needed.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you are using the unpacked perl install, make sure you are not using Unicode::Collate version 1.18+ at the moment because that removed XS code and this makes  it a lot slower. The  new release enforces version 1.17 for unpacked installs.

Comment: @PLK: thanks a lot! Could you explain your last point and tell me, what to do or not to do?

Comment: I made a mistake there - I meant Unicode::Normalize, not Unicode::Collate.  So, if you are using the raw perl install, then do this: `perl -MUnicode::Normalize -E 'say $Unicode::Normalize::VERSION;'` and make sure it does not return anthing greater than `1.17`

Comment: @PLK: _"and make sure it does not return anything greater than 1.17", well it does: It returns 1.18. So what to do now?

Comment: This is no longer an issue as Unicode::Normalize >=1.22 has XSUB back in. So just upgrade to the latest Unicode::Normalize and you'll be alright.

Comment: Finally... What should we do to get a faster Biber?
Can we try to compile anything with tools such as pp?

Answer (score 3):

If not using a binary biber release, that is if you are downloading biber perl source and installing yourself, make sure you have `Unicode::Normalize` >= 1.22 as this reinstated the XSUB version and is dramatically faster. When you do `perl Build.PL`, you will be warned if you don't have the latest `Unicode::Normalize` and as usual, `Build installdeps` will install the latest version along with all other dependencies.