# Latex measure compilation time of specific parts of document

Tags: compiling

due to long compilation time of a complex tex-file I would like to measure specific code parts inside this tex-file.
I tried using l3benchmark (https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental/l3benchmark.pdf) but I can only run it on the whole document not on specific parts.

I tried to run \benchmark_once:n { specific code part } & \benchmark_silent:n { specific code part } already.
on top of the document I included the l3benchmark package once with \RequirePackage{l3benchmark}
and once with \usepackage{l3benchmark} for each method.

Am I missing something or how could it be possible to just measure the compilation time of parts of the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please let us at least know what document class you are using.

Comment: if you're using pdftex, maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211572/7674) could help?

Comment: It is possible to measure any part. If you can use LuaLaTeX, I can post some code. I use this code to read the time elapsed between 2 points in a document, using the socket library for Lua.

Comment: Hey @barbarabeeton, if I read my master.tex file correctly I am using "\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}" with lualatex. 
So yes with using lualatex (yiannislazarides) your code could be of good help. Do you have an example that you want to share for better understanding?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides -- A comment from the OP says "yes with using lualatex [...] your code could be of good help."  Since a comment here can only ping one person, I think you probably didn't see it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I have added some code.

Answer (score 4):

Here some lua code for timing performance of code. The `socket` library is build-in with the LuaTeX compiler, ensure is enabled with the --socket option. As you will see LaTeX programs run very **fast**. They are slowed down by loading too many large fonts, large images and tikz graphics.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mytimer.lua}

-- table to hold time performance           
 M = M or {}
  local socket = require('socket')
  local time_stat = time_stat or {}
  local gettime = socket.gettime
   
-- start time measurement
time_stat["total"] = 0

-- @param done indicates timer was stopped
function start_time_measure(field)        
    time_stat[field] = {start = gettime(), done = false}
end

-- stop time measurement   
-- if two calls to stop will return wrong value
function stop_time_measure(field)         
    if not time_stat[field].done then 
       time_stat[field] = {total = gettime() - time_stat[field].start, done=true} 
    end   
end



 M.start = start_time_measure
 M.stop  = stop_time_measure 
 M.statistics = function(name) return time_stat[name].total end

-- M.start("document")
-- local s = 0
-- for i=1, 1 do s=s+1 end 
-- M.stop("document")

-- print(M.statistics("document"))
-- print(M.statistics("document"))
return M
\end{filecontents*}

\directlua{timer = require("mytimer")}
\def\timerstart#1{\directlua{timer.start("#1")}}
\def\timerstop#1{\directlua{timer.stop("#1")}}
\def\timerprint#1{
\directlua{
timer.stop("#1")
tex.print("elapsed time (#1):", timer.statistics("#1").." s")
}}
\timerstart{document}
\documentclass{article}
\timerstart{package}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\timerstop{package}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Hello
\timerprint{package}
\begin{luacode}
z=0
for i=0,150000000,1 do
  i=i+1
  z=i
end
tex.print(z)
\end{luacode}

\timerstart{lipsum}
\lipsum[1-12]
\timerstop{lipsum}

\timerprint{package}

\timerprint{lipsum}

\timerprint{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for nice answer. I added your code to OpTeX tricks too. See http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#timer

Comment: I have found that elapsed time reported by `time lualatex --socket document` is about 0.6 second more than elapsed time printed by \timerprint (in my computer). The reason is: LuaLaTeX does an extensive work in `\everyjob`, namely it loads `luaotfload` which spend 0.25 seconds. On the other hand, `time optex` reports only 0.2 s more, because luaotfload is loaded when first `\fontfam` is used. I compare time of the whole document with `\lipsum[1-12]`, without the loop 0,150000000 and with `luaotfolad` initialized: `time lualatex` reports 1.65 s and `time optex` reports 0.65 s.

Comment: @wipet  Thanks. It is about time I try OpTeX again. Tried it some years back, but I see it has come a long way, especially the English documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @YiannisLazarides! This helps a bit to find out why my latex file compilation is too slow.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides - Another question that came up regarding your code. Does it matter if I use that lua code inside the tex-file itself or import it from a separate lua-file where I insert your code? Seems I am not getting the time for specific parts each time I am compiling the tex-file. Thinking of tracing race conditions right now, as including some try-catch logic into the lua-code didn't help. 
Have you ever noticed something similar or did your code always print the time correctly?

Comment: @simonroof  It should work both ways.